# Create Range of Numbers in if Statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a range of values 1768 to 1815 and I have my if statement

```
if (location.x = 1768 to 1815) 
{
    //perform code
}
```

Do i create an array or how can I do this?  Sorry I am new to programming

Comment: So, is your question, "How can I write an `if` statement in objective C to test if `location.x` is greater than or equal to 1768 and `location.x` is also less than or equal to 1815?`"

Comment: Rob Napier's answer is what I would suggest.  I recommend looking at the basics of C programming.  His answer touches upon conditionals, expressions (evaluating to true or false... 0 or nonzero), and the "and" operator. If you didn't know these exist, it would be nearly impossible to have come up with his solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (location.x >= 1768 && location.x <= 1815)
```